# Sphinx search in specific folder (php)

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

i'm new to sphinx indexer and i was trying to understand it through an existing code **(PHP)** at work,
I found that the indexer can place the indexed data anywhere we like if we modify the config file and set the path to it.
I checked for the validity of the index by dumping the number of files in the index and it is working fine.
but when i use the **searchd** functionality to search in that index, it searches in the specified folder where all the indexes were initially placed and not in the new folder i had created,
so I deduced that while searching, the index's path is not fetched from the config file (verified it)

--  I can't seem to figure out how the sphinx search only searches in that very folder? I couldnt find the same folder path anywhere in the code. Is there a way to tell the sphinx search to search in an index in a particular folder.

-- Also, the files created in the new folder have **.new** appended to the index files. I read it in the documentation that **.new** was appended to the files while the data is being indexed and it is renamed to the actual index name once the indexing is complete, but it is not being renamed in my case, could it be because i had another index with the similar name in the initial path aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you set config file when you call searchd? Like so :

```
searchd --config "config_path"
```

Or config placed in default place? I mean, maybe you have 2 separate config files?